# How to use Global hook meanwhile suppress App hook?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, keyevent

I got stuck the whole morning. I was trying to listen to mouse & keyboard event meanwhile excluding any event happening to the application.
But I cannot get it work. Any ideas or code snippets?

My idea is like the following.

```
private IKeyboardMouseEvents? m_Events;
...
SubscribeGlobal();
// try to unsubscribe mouse&keyboard event in app?
```

I am expecting the mouse & keyboard event within the app is ignored.